# How to join single record from one table with multiple records in table 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
CUST    Track
1        100
2        100
3        200
4        200
```

Table 2

```
Track   Data 
100       A
100       B
100       C
100       D
200       X
200       Y
200       Z
200       P
```

Output

```
CUST       Track    Data 
1           100      A
                     B
                     C
                     D
2           100      A
                     B
                     C
                     D
3          200       X
                     Y
                     Z
                     P
3          200       X
                     Y
                     Z
                     P
```

I want CUST,Track only one time in output and DATA I want all records as per above output.

Comment: Is this a selection question or a formatting question? For selection, it is simply a join of the two tables. Formatting depends upon what tool you are using.

Comment: using SQL is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible, just not the right tool for it. For example, this is fairly easy to do in SSRS or Excel.

Comment: SQL is absolutely the right tool. Select from table1, join table2, and you're done. Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html#rrefsqlj35034 . Use an outer join if you want to include records from table1 with no corresponding records from table2.

Comment: @dmfay, you cannot selectively output a column in a row and exclude it in another. Check my first comment here, Mahesh is not looking for a selection answer but rather a formatting answer.

Comment: I want it in sql only.. If possible could u provide me the code

Comment: @Anand ah, you're right; I misread the output. A pure SQL solution might still be possible by abusing `GROUPING SETS` in a subquery or something, but that's probably inadvisable anyway.

Comment: Not everything that is possible should actually be done. This is a perfect example. As a dataset, the rows where CUST and TRACK are null make no sense. This is a report formatting problem; there is absolutely no data application of the output where the CUST and TRACK are masked by NULL in all rows but one. The desired outcome is very easy to achieve, for example, in SQL\*Plus, or probably in any front-end to the Oracle database. Don't do it in the result set itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to put all the data in a single row like this:

```
CUST       Track    Data 
1           100      A,B,C,D
```

This is easy to produce:

```
select t1.custid, t2.track, listagg(data, ',') within group (order by data) as data
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.track = t2.track
group by t1.custid, t2.track;
```

This format is not a requirement.  It is possible to produce the output you want.  However, that output is rather strange in a SQL context, because it has inter-row dependencies.  Normally, a row in a SQL table or result set represents something, without reference to "adjacent" rows.